# does http response get sent to client or to load balancer

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

Assuming of following configuration:

```
Client -> NginX -> nodejs server
```

When a client sends a request, it hits the load balancer and gets routed to the server. Then, inside my node.js app, when I catch the request and call `res.end()`, is the response **routed back to the load balancer then to the client**, or it's being sent **directly to the client**?

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.end('hello!'); // where does the response go internally?
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If it would get back to the load balancer, shouldn't you see it in it's logs?

Comment: In the case above, response always sent to nginx.

Comment: @Alexey Ten - We need the response code

Comment: @mikeb, I don't understand. What do you mean?